# Potential Energy Diagrams and the Effect of Catalysts

Tags: catalysis

Why does a potential energy diagram showing the effect of a catalyst on activation energy not move left on the reaction pathway scale (compared to uncatalysed reaction) if a catalyst speeds up reactions?

Comment: You might be imagining that we all have the same textbook as you, opened on the same page, and are looking at the same picture as you. I hate to break it to you, but this is not so.

Comment: You should provide the diagram. To do this, take a clear photo of the picture, and then upload it by using the image upload option that appears on the top bar when editing or posting the question.

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is the first time I've used this sight. I am not a chemistry expert by any means; I'm just sitting higher. I have got the answer now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the reaction coordinate does not indicate speed.
It represents a certain state of the reaction (e.g. 50 % completed) but it does not have any information about time in it.

Therefore the higher reaction speed is not represented in those diagrams.